# ip2location ip database shows that the location is wrong, how do I update?

Tags: ip

ip:148.153.82.27
United States of America [US] 
https://www.ip2location.com/demo/148.153.82.27

Correct information
Frankfurt, Hesse, Germany

Comment: You should contact IP2Location regarding this issue.

Comment: You  have an old database. I get:

c:\>geoip 148.153.82.27
DE, Germany              loc: Frankfurt am Main/Hessen     
  Pos: 50.116N, 8.684E
  URL: https://www.google.com/maps/@50.11552,8.68417,10z